# Google AdMob Test Banner Not Showing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, admob

I'm having trouble displaying the Google AdMob test banner. I created a simple application as described in their docs https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start#manually_using_the_sdk_download. The only difference from that sample is that I'm using a `UINavigationController`

[image: Google AdMob Placement]

After looking around for a solution to another issue I found that by adding `[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];` on my `ViewController` the banner appeared!

Has anyone run into this? What workarounds/fixes are there? Am I doing something wrong?

### UPDATE 1

I created a sample project so you can see and test. I created Tags along the way to make it easy for you to navigate backwards as I made my changes. https://github.com/RoLYroLLs/GoogleAdMobTest.

One important thing to note is that as I made my changes, the ad doesn't appear when the label AND the textview were removed from the view (check tag `v0.1.3`. When I removed either one the ad did show up (check tags: `v0.1.1` and `v0.1.2`).

In tag `v0.1.5` I added `[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone]` to make it work, but I don't like what it does to the tab bar and the navigation bar, they look darker or something.

Any feedback is welcome. Thanks!

### UPDATE 2

The issue seems to be fixed when using Xcode 6.0.1. I guess it was a bug in Xcode 5.x.x?

Comment: I couldn't test your code because I get "To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = .." . Its to do with how you generated the adUnit i believe.

Comment: Hi @Zigglzworth, thanks for testing. I get that message too, even when it does work. However, that is Google's sample code they show in their instructions (https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/master/admob/BannerExample/BannerExample/ViewController.m). Also, if you use Git to reset your `HEAD` to `v0.1.5` the same code works, just has a different layout.

Comment: i am having the same issue with Xcode 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it was a bug in Xcode 5.x.x as I just upgraded to Xcode 6.0.1 and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the proper auto layout constraints so when the view shifts behind the navigation bar, the banner adjusts itself.

The banner should have the following constraints:

- leading space to superview
- trailing space to superview
- top space to top layout guide

The tableView should have the following constraints

- vertical spacing to admob banner
- leading space to superview
- trailing space to superview
- bottom space to bottom layout guide

You can set the constraints visually in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks @Kris-Gellci. I verified and I do have those constraints.